# О проблеме перевода топонимов на другие языки

Tags: топонимика, переводы

Я живу на Украине, а точнее - в Крыму. Край у нас русскоязычный, поэтому всегда все названия (улиц, городов, поселков и т.д.) на дорожных указателях писались по-русски. Но сейчас, в рамках всеобщей украинизации, их стали переводить на украинский. И если б просто переводить! Их стали писать в виде транскрипций украинскими буквами.
И я хочу спросить специалистов, как правильно и грамотно поступать в подобных ситуациях? Например, "проспект Победы" у нас в указателе значится как "проспект Победи" (хотя, если уж правильно транскрибировать, то надо было написать "Побєди"), а не "проспект Перемоги", село "Прiятне свiданiє" (по-русски - Приятное Свидание), а не "Приємне побачення".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала: не поминайте специалистов. Вопрос очень политизирован и три специалиста будут иметь четыре попарно взаимоисключащих мнения.
Но вообще говоря, вариант транскрибирования представляется самым разумным. Имена собственные - в т.ч. топонимы - не преводятся а именно транскрибируются. Правда тут дело осложняется спроностью первичности названия. Если вдруг окажется, что исходно названия давались на украиснком языке, то придется транскрибировать уже на русский. 
По этому поводу. Я давненько не был в Крыму, но хорошо помню ситуацию начала 60-х годов. Многие названия были уже тогда украинскими. Я не мог не обратить на это внимание, ибо читать уже умел - и с превеликой охотой читал все вывески и таблички. На украинских спотыкался - и терроризировал старших, что это за буква такая или слово. Так что не могу исключить принятия тогдашним горисполкомом украинского варианта названия как основного и первичного.

И еще. Транскрибирование тоже может быть основано на разных принципах, в частности ваше однозначное заключение о том, что однозначно надо "Побєди" а не "Победи" не совсем правильно. Зависит от подхода. Вариант "Победи" вполне имеет право на существование, т.к. точнее передаёт фонетику языка-мишении.

*Село "Прiятне свiданiє"*. А вот это, полагаю, косяк. Русскому прилагательному пришита украинская флексия. Это уже не транскрибирование а искусственная ассимиляция. Типа французское с нижегородским. Хотя тоже надо повнимательнее посмотреть, чем "переводчики" руководствовались.